# Chapterbib for multiple bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, chapterbib

I am writing my PhD thesis and I am using chapterbib to have different bibliographies for different chapters. I run compile from the main file, then the Bibliography in each of the .aux files and then compile from the main file again. The .bib files are in the same subfolder where I have the single chapters. However, although I manage to compile the bibliographies, it seems I am not able to add more citations (I cannot use the command \cite any longer). Any ideas about this?

Thanks a lot.

The main file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{palatino}

%declare images folder
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}
\urlstyle{same}


\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{20pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{20pt}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{20pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{20pt}
}
\makeatother

\allowdisplaybreaks


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\Huge
\textbf{Thesis Title}

\vspace{3cm}

\large
A thesis submitted to...

\vspace{1.5cm}
\textbf{Year of submission}

\vspace{1.5cm}
\textbf{Author Name}

\vspace{1.5cm}
School of Social Sciences \\
Economics
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\include{chapters/abstract}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\include{chapters/declaration}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Copyright Statement}
\include{chapters/copyright_statement}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\include{chapters/acknowledgements}

\include{chapters/introduction}

\include{chapters/chapter02}

\include{chapters/chapter03}

\include{chapters/conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried deleting all the aux files? sometimes that helps

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this did not help.